# Python regex [group separator[

Tags: python, regex

This is the output I have: `['5', '+', '4X1', '-', '9.3X2']`

The output I want is : `['5', '+4X1', '-9.3X2']`

How can I achieve that?

```
import re
import sys

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'


 def parse(str):
    for ch in[' ', '^', '*', 'X0']:
        if ch in str:
            str = str.replace(ch, '')
    str = str.split(('='))
    left = str[0]
    right = str[1]
    left = re.split("(\+|\-)", left)
    print left

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        parse(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        print ("please enter your string in one argument in this form: \n\t"
        + bcolors.OKGREEN + "5 * X^0 + 4 * X^1 - 9.3 * X^2 = 1 * X^0" + bcolors.ENDC)
```

Thank you for help of any kind !

Comment: Any updates? Has your issue been resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for your example:

```
def clean_data(data):
    data_iter = iter(data)
    for item in data_iter:
        if item in {'+', '-'}:
            yield item + next(data_iter)
        else:
            yield item


data = ['5', '+', '4X1', '-', '9.3X2']
new_data = clean_data(data)

print(list(new_data))  # ['5', '+4X1', '-9.3X2']
```

Comment: This work perfectly ! Thank you very much. Easier than complex regex, and  way more digestible (I've just started learning python, coming from C).

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate issue is that the line `left = re.split("(\+|\-)", left)` includes the `+` or `-` symbols in the output as separate items, while you want the symbol to be combined with the number that follows it.

A possible solution is to use `re.findall` rather than `re.split`, and not use any capturing groups:

```
left = re.findall(r'(?:^|[+-])\d+(?:\.\d?)X\d+', left)
```

Another alternative would be to get rid of the string replacement calls you're currently doing and just use `re.findall` directly on the input string from the user. You'd have to reassemble the result tuples into a string (assuming you really need that at all), but that's easy to do with `str.join`:

```
def parse(s):
    pattern = r'(^|[+-])\s*(\d+(?:\.\d?))\s*\*\s*(X)\^(\d+)'
    return ["".join(x) for x in re.findall(pattern, s)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `split` on `0 width assertion` which is not supported by `re` but `regex` module.

```
x="5+4X1-9.3X2"
print regex.split(r"(?=[+-])",x,flags=regex.VERSION1)
```

Output:`['5', '+4X1', '-9.3X2']`